# Debug through the disassembled code (with Visual Studio)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, debugging, disassembly

There is a lot of disassemblers witch allows seeing the internal structure of .NET base assemblies.

Is there a way, add-in or similar for Visual Studio that will permit debugging through the disassembled code?

By example I have a user control I set the Width = 100 but the width always remains to 200. After a half on hour I remarked that the Minimum Size was set to 200. I reset the MinimumSize, but this does not help, With would not to change.

Answer (score 1):

You don't decompile the code - you [tell Visual Studio to use a Microsoft symbol server to get the code from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx). The most important bit of that page is this:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1
>   connects to the Microsoft public
>   symbol servers automatically when you
>   click Load symbols from Microsoft
>   symbol servers in the Options dialog
>   box (Debugging category, Symbols page)
>   or the shortcut menu (in the Modules
>   Window of Call Stack Window).

Note that you can only press the "Load symbols..." button when you're already debugging - otherwise it's disabled.

You'll need to accept the licence from Microsoft to do this, but it's the right way to do it.

Comment: @serhio: When you go through the process, it asks you to accept a licence. At least, I believe it does - I'm trying it now :)

Comment: @Jon: yeah. I should accept a license agreement - no pbs. But... **it asks me for a source file... of UserControl.cs ??!!**

Comment: @serhio: After saying to load symbols from the Microsoft server? That's odd. I'll try to reproduce in a little sandbox.

Comment: I see only the stack calls method names. If I double click on the one of them it says that (i translate from french) there is no code available code for the current line/location...

Comment: @Jon: apparently it search in *"f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\WinForms\Managed\System\WinForms\Control.cs"*, where F should be my CD location.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I'm afraid I don't know how to do it with vs2005 - I suspect that's the problem.